# Join help in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I have 2 very simple tables to join but I am missing somewhere badly that I am not getting the desired output:

Table #1:

[image]

Table #2:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Query:

```
create table #temp1
(
     client_id int, 
     identifier int, 
     pp_id int,
     ch_id int,
     code varchar(20),
     program varchar(20),
     startdate date,
     enddate date, 
     ssc varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp1
values (9908,789654123,1567,1566,'OP','xASMT','1/1/2019','1/4/2019','A201901044F010134NNN01D               151 143 093 ')

create table #temp2
(
     client_id int, 
     identifier int, 
     pp_id int,
     ch_id int,
     code varchar(20), 
     program varchar(20),
     startdate date,
     enddate date, 
     ssc varchar(20)
)

insert into #temp2
values(9908,789654123,1574,1573,'OP','SU1','1/1/2019','1/4/2019',NULL)

--My query:
select 
    t1.client_id, t1.identifier, 
    concat(t1.code, t1.startdate, t1.enddate, t1.ssc),
    concat(t2.code, t2.startdate, t2.enddate, t2.ssc)
from 
    #temp1 t1
left join 
    #temp2 t2 on t1.client_id = t2.client_id and t1.identifier = t2.identifier
```

I am still a learner and pardon me if there are any mistakes here. Any help?!

Comment: What is the issue, what are you getting that is the problem?

Comment: NOTE: If any values are null and you build a string it will make the entire string null

Comment: My query is not giving me the desired output. I need 2 lines of records

Comment: I am only concatenating the dates and SSC. If if anything is null it will be reported as null

Comment: A join will try to join the records and give you one for every unique match. Are you needing to do a UNION instead?

Comment: This isn't a JOIN, it's a UNION.

Comment: Yeah. Just figured, UNION is helpful. Is there any other way to accomplish this with JOIN?

Comment: @brad not with CONCAT, only with +

Comment: @rick UNION makes resultsets grow vertically, JOIN makes them grow horizontally. You've specifically indicated you want vertical growth; why are you asking for JOIN?

Comment: @caius thanks. I understood now!

Comment: I mean, you CAN do it with JOIN; i'll post an example for you if you really, really want..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what you WOULDN'T do, just posting because you asked about JOIN. It's definitely the wrong way to go, but:

```
select 
  COALESCE(t1.client_id, t2.client_id) client_id,
  COALESCE(t1.identifier, t2.identifier) identifier,
  COALESCE(
    CONCAT(t1.code,t1.startdate,t1.enddate,t1.ssc),  
    concat(t2.code,t2.startdate,t2.enddate,t2.ssc)
  )
from 
  #temp1 t1
  full outer join 
  #temp2 t2 
  on 0 = 1
```

A full outer join between these tables on an impossible condition means you end up with a resultset like:

```
t1.client_id t2.client_id
9908         NULL
NULL         9908
```

The COALESCE brings the split-ness of it back together:

```
client_id
9908
9908
```

As noted, don't do it- it's a huge waste of the database's time and resources compared to union; I purely wrote it as an example of how vertical growth of a resultset can be achieved using JOINs and also as an aid to your understanding of db theory and operation:

```
A UNION B (number is id)

Results grow vertically:
A1
A2
B1
B2

A JOIN B (number is id)

Results grow horizontally:
A1 B1
A2 B2
```

Outer joins preserve the row from the table even if there is no match:

```
A OUTER JOIN B

Results:
A1   null
null B2
```

By making the join impossible, a full outer join will cause a resultset that grew horizontally and vertically:

```
A OUTER JOIN B ON 1 = 0

Results:
A1   null
A2   null
null B1
null B2
```

COALESCE returns the first non-null argument, so if we COALESCE(a_column, b_column) it collapses those two columns, one of which is null, into one column:

```
acol bcol  COALESCE(acol, bcol)  result
----|-----|--------------------|--------
A1   null  COALESCE(A1, null)   -> A1
null B2    COALESCE(null, B1)   -> B1
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe you need a join, but you need union:

```
select t1.client_id, t1.identifier, CONCAT(t1.code,t1.startdate,t1.enddate,t1.ssc)
from #temp1 t1
union all
select t2.client_id, t2.identifier, CONCAT(t2.code,t2.startdate,t2.enddate,t2.ssc)
from #temp2 t2
```

maybe you need a `where` part to restrict the result for certain rows. 
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ccd279fd211d60ea10970fd5d6ef7b25)

Answer (score 3):

What you seem to look for is a `UNION` select construct, not a join.

UNION returns rows from one sub-query and appends rows from another sub-query

So with your example

```
select t1.client_id, t1.identifier, CONCAT(t1.code,t1.startdate,t1.enddate,t1.ssc
from #temp1 t1 
where ... some condition ...
union all 
select t2.client_id, t2.identifier, concat(t2.code,t2.startdate,t2.enddate,t2.ssc)
from #temp2 t2 
where ... some condition ...
```

See docs here: [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your desired result I understand you need to use UNION ALL instead of join the tables.

Please check the script :

```
SELECT
    t1.client_id
   ,t1.identifier
   ,CONCAT(t1.code, t1.startdate, t1.enddate, t1.ssc)
   --,CONCAT(t2.code, t2.startdate, t2.enddate, t2.ssc)
FROM #temp1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    t2.client_id
   ,T2.identifier
   ,CONCAT(t2.code, t2.startdate, t2.enddate, t2.ssc)
FROM  #temp2 t2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would use to get that output:

```
select 
    t1.client_id, 
    t1.identifier, 
    CONCAT(t1.code,t1.startdate,t1.enddate,t1.ssc) ssc_concatenated
    --concat(t2.code,t2.startdate,t2.enddate,t2.ssc)

from #temp1 t1

union all

select 
    t2.client_id, 
    t2.identifier, 
    concat(t2.code,t2.startdate,t2.enddate,t2.ssc) ssc_concatenated
from #temp2 t2
```

Here's the db<>fiddle [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=007d8ecc985e5dc991c2d8e42afe1534)